# Deeply comparing two lists of tuples (Python)

Tags: python, list

I am very new to Python and, in fact, programming as such.
What I have are two lists of tuples with no duplicates between them (the lists are the result of eliminating duplicate tuples by list comprehension).
I want to find intersections within the contained tuples (new/deleted/changed) and have created this example:

Lists of tuples with groups and items and counters:

```
list1 = [("fruits","apple",1),("fruits","banana",1),("legumes","bean",3),("meats","deadbeef",1),("meats","pork",2)]

list2 = [("fruits","apple",2),("fruits","mango",4),("legumes","pea",3),("plants","rose",1)]
```

My goal is something like this:

```
*Report*:

New group:     "plants"    with item "rose", count 2

Deleted group: "meats"     with items "deadbeef", count 1, "pork", count 2

New item in group "fruits": "mango", count 4

New item in group "legumes": "pea", count 3

Deleted item in group "fruits": "banana", count 1

Deleted item in group "legumes": "bean", count 3

Changed item in group "fruits": item "apple" new count 2, old count 1
```

Any help is highly appreciated, since I am totally stuck how to even start :(

Not even sure whether I have chosen the right data structures, so I am totally open for every hint.

Thanks,

Joel

Comment: For data structures, nested dictionaries would make sense: `{"fruits": {"apple": 1, "banana": 1}, "legumes": {"bean": 3}, "meats": {"deadbeef": 1, "pork": 2}}`. Then you compare two levels of keys and the values.

Comment: Since you have eliminated duplicates (and, I assume, there are no duplicate items inside a single tuple), use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = [("fruits","apple",1),("fruits","banana",1),("legumes","bean",3),("meats","deadbeef",1),("meats","pork",2)]
list2 = [("fruits","apple",2),("fruits","mango",4),("legumes","pea",3),("plants","rose",1)]
group1 = set([i[0] for i in list1])
group2 = set([i[0] for i in list2])
newItems = group2 - group1
print "New group:"+str(newItems)   #you can write logic for >>> with item "rose", count 2

dict1 = {}
for i in list1:
    dict1[i[1]] = i[2]
dict2 = {}
for i in list2:
    dict2[i[1]] = i[2]

totalkeys = set(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys())
for item in totalkeys:
    if dict1.has_key(item):
        if dict2.has_key(item):
            if dict1[item] ==dict2[item]:
                pass
            else:
                #your logic for change val
                pass
        else:
            pass #your logic for new item in list 2
    else:
        pass #your logic for deleted item
```

you can put the print statment as you need just replace pass to print "whatever"